# Splitwise API returns "Invalid OAuth Request" after requesting accessToken

Tags: ios, oauth

I'm using an iOS-compatible version of the OAuthConsumer library, and trying to authenticate against Splitwise's API. After acquiring the requestToken and verifier, I request an accessToken like so:

```
- (void)getAuthorizedAccessToken:(NSString *)pin {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://secure.splitwise.com/api/v3.0/get_access_token"];
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:self.consumer
                                                                      token:self.accessToken
                                                                      realm:nil
                                                          signatureProvider:nil];
    OARequestParameter *token = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_token" value:self.accessToken.key];
    OARequestParameter *verifier = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_secret" value:pin];
    [request setParameters:@[token, verifier]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(accessTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(accessTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
    NSLog(@"Sent access-token OAuth request");
}
```

But when my didFinishWithData function is returned, all I get outputted is an error: "Invalid OAuth Request", when I'd expect this to be successful.

```
- (void)accessTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"accessTokenTicket didFinishWithData");
    if (ticket.didSucceed) {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
        [self.accessToken storeInUserDefaultsWithServiceProviderName:@"WhoPays" prefix:@"WP"];
        [self testAPIConnection];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
}
```

I've compared my code to this working version against Twitter and I think my logic appears to be in order:
https://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer-iphone/source/browse/trunk/examples/oauthTwitterApp/Classes/oauthTwitterAppViewController.m

My whole code can be found here:
https://github.com/crummy/whopays/blob/master/WhoPays%3F/WPWelcomeViewController.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Crummy – Ryan from Splitwise here. I'm just about to head out of the office for the weekend, so I didn't get a chance to test this myself, but I can see at least one bug in your code: you're initializing `OARequestParameter *verifier` with the wrong name (`"oauth_secret"` instead of `"oauth_verifier"`).

Also, it's possible you may need to adjust your code so that `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier` are passed as part of the "Authorization" HTTP header, rather than as POST parameters. Our server-side OAuth implementation is a bit finicky, and I'm not sure it allows those values outside the header. If you follow our [docs](http://dev.splitwise.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=get_access_token) to the letter, everything ought to work okay.

Hope that helps! If you're still having issues, let us know here or at developers@splitwise.com and we'll get back to you on Monday :)

**EDIT:** Just in case someone comes across this post later, it turns out the issue was (1) fixing the parameter name as outlined above and (2) making sure the request was made via POST, not GET.

Comment: That's great - I got confused with all the tokens and secrets and keys and verifiers. I've updated the github repository, but I now get a 404 page returned when I hit the test API here: https://github.com/crummy/whopays/blob/master/WhoPays%3F/WPWelcomeViewController.m#L60

Comment: It looks like `testAPIConnection` actually isn't being called at all – the `get_access_token` phase is still failing. (In `accessTokenTicket:didFinishWithData`, `ticket.didSucceed` is equal to `NO`, so `testAPIConnection` never fires.) Have you tried moving the `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier` params to the HTTP header, like I mentioned above? Like I said, not sure if our server accepts them as POST parameters – if not, I can add that to our bug list, but it'll probably take us some time to fix.